# React-native Google map Polyine shadow?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps

I have build map based application in react-native. and i am using react-native google-maps library for this. i have looking for solution to two of my question? cant figure out how to solve them.

1. How can i add shadow to polyline ?
2. How can i make my polyline to start from given marker.

Screenshots are given below they might help you what i am saying.

[How to add shadow to given polyline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZqQi.jpg)
[Connect Polyline and marker together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwYSA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are using react-native google-maps library. Do you mean the [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps) library? If so, have you tried the [react-native-maps Polyline](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/polyline.md)? You can change the polyline's stroke property but not adding shadow. If you would like you can create another polyline with the same coordinates(path) and change the stroke properties that will look like a shadow of the polyline. You can also set the coordinates of this polyline to start and end from a certain coordinates or your markers.

Here's a [sample code](https://snack.expo.io/bLSanSHUq) and code snippet below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Marker, Polyline } from 'react-native-maps';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
  },
});

class MapApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      coords: [
        { latitude: 37.7948605, longitude: -122.4596065 },
        { latitude: 37.8025259, longitude: -122.4351431 },
      ],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 37.7948605,
            longitude: -122.4596065,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}>
          {this.state.coords.map((coords, index) => (
            <Marker key={index} coordinate={coords} />
          ))}

          <Polyline
            coordinates={this.state.coords}
            //strokeColor="#000" // fallback for when `strokeColors` is not supported by the map-provider
            strokeColor={'rgb(0, 0, 0)'}
            strokeWidth={6}
          />
          <Polyline
            coordinates={this.state.coords}
            //this is the polyline for shadow
            strokeColor={'rgba(0, 0, 0,0.3)'}
            strokeWidth={15}
          />
        </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default MapApp;
```